# Tool to search my disk for trimmed mp3s with unexpected ending

Tags: windows, music, mp3, file-search

It should find short mp3s with a loud unexpected ending (e.g. incomplete downloads).

It would be good to have also a feature there to fade out track ends in a batch.

It must be free or for low budget.

Comment: I'm not sure how to formulate it. I mean when you download a song and it's aborted at a half when you listen it ends unexpectedly.

Comment: Ah, "incomplete" you mean. Updated your post accordingly. Good luck then!